# Streaming an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, stream, lazy-evaluation, yield-return, textreader

I have a list of strings that is being read in from a file and filtered, all of which is happening using the yield mechanisms so that it is lazy. I then need to pass this into a method which takes a TextReader.

Is there anything wrong with this method? It seems to work, but wanted to know I had missed something.

```
public class EnumerableReader : TextReader
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<string> _enumerator;

    public EnumerableReader(IEnumerable<string> lines)
    {
        _enumerator = lines.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public override string ReadLine()
    {
        return _enumerator.MoveNext() ? _enumerator.Current : null;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _enumerator.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to `Dispose` the IEnumerator<string> when you're done.

Comment: @dtb I'm genuinly curious in this case why Disposing the `_enumerator` actively would be better than letting the garbage collector do it when needed ? Memory consumption?

Comment: @SimonBelanger: Generally, because *though shalt dispose your IDisposables*. In this situation the IEnumerator reads from a file; you'll probably do not want to keep the file open until the GC eventually closes it, but close it deterministically.

Comment: What if I add the Dispose like how I have updated my example?

Answer (score 4):

The [TextReader Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx) exposes multiple methods to read data. If you pass an instance to some external code, it may use any of the methods, not just the [ReadLine Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readline.aspx).

The methods that you need to override at a minimum are the [Read Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w3csw16.aspx) and the [Peek Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.peek.aspx). If you don't override them, they both always returns -1, indicating that the end has been reached. All other methods, including the [ReadLine Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readline.aspx), provide default implementations based the [Read Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w3csw16.aspx). You can override them (for example, for improved performance), but you are not required to.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx):

> **Notes to Inheritors**
>
> A derived class must minimally implement the [Peek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.peek.aspx) and [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w3csw16.aspx) methods to make a useful instance of TextReader.

So your implementation does not work as is.

Comment: What if the Method using the Stream only ever calls `ReadLine()`?

Comment: @Schotime If you know that, then you probably shouldn't use `TextReader`, but a custom type.